# tooltip echo $row->description

Tags: tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am trying to echo the result of a db $row->description in jquery ui tooltip.  The tooltip will display most my other PHP $row requests like images and titles, but it will not echo the description from my db.  It seems to have this problem when the description is very long.

So in other words the tooltip displays $row->description when it is very short, but if the description is long then nothing displays at all.

I tried using strip_tags($row->description) on this but that didn't seem to work either.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post an example of a string which fails?

Comment: well if it pulls a small description from the db like "Cookies and Milk" it will display it.  But if the description is larger than 50 characters or so it won't display it.  I tried abbreviate(), strip_tags() on it but nothing is helping.

Comment: I was wondering whether some special characters in the description was breaking it.

Comment: By special chars do you mean '=', '1234', '$', etc?  Many of the descriptions have these.  But nothing really unorthodox.  Does jquery ui have a problem with these type?

Comment: It should cope with most things. I was just trying to establish what makes one string work but on other fail. Length alone doesn't sound like the problem. Try to post an example of a string which fails.

Comment: Okay, after some testing I think I narrowed it down.  "Does this work?" works.  "afsljkfasdljkafsdjlkafsdjasfdlkjafsdkjlafsdjklasfdkljasfdkjafsdljk" also works.  But if it has two lines of text like, "stuff"<br>"stuff", then it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could try stripping out any control characters such as newlines etc.